# Permission denied when trying to echo "hello" into /dev/ttys0

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, uart

I've connected my raspberry pi 3 B+ to my laptop using the UART pins (GPIO 14 and 15) and a TTL - USB cable.

I understood that after using the command below, the string should be appear in the raspberry's terminal, so all I'm trying to do is to write to ttyS0 and transfer data to the raspberry pi using UART:

`echo “Hello” > /dev/ttyS0`

- My user is a member in the dialout group.
- UART is enabled for Serial Communication on RX and TX pin of raspberry pi.

I'd love to get some wisdom.

**edit**:
now is says:
`bash: echo: write error: Input/output error`

Comment: Without any deeper insight, just thinking about the OS running on the RasPI: Don't you need to login over that interface? You might want to use a terminal program on your laptop to check things out.

Comment: I logged to the Pi and even connect with SSH, if that what u meant. I can use the Pi's terminal from my laptop.

Comment: Great, that shows that the physical connection works. Now there is "only" the protocol part left. You might want to try to communicate on a lower level, SSH does a lot under the hood. What it prints and what you enter, is not what goes over the connection.

Comment: What/which is **the raspberry pi's terminal**? How are you logged into the pi, are you sure that what you're looking at (be it logged in or via ssh) is in fact `/dev/ttyS0`? If I'm logged into a GUI, for example, I'm connected to things like `/dev/pts/1` in an xterm, via ssh I am on e.g. `/dev/pts/12` ...

Comment: The terminal I use for the SSH is /dev/pts/1 and when I use ``` echo "hello" > /dev/pts/1 ``` it's shown on the PI's terminal. if that so, how can I do a simple check and transfer data as I did with the SSH between my Pi & computer via UART?

Comment: As I said: which tty/pty/pts is connected to the terminal you're watching? We can't see that ....

Comment: on my PC: 
tty2 - Xorg & gnome,
pts/1 - ssh,
pts/0 - ps,

on the Pi:
tty1 - bash,
pts/0 - ps

is that it?

Comment: Your question is not programming related; it belongs on superuser.com.  You also need to describe the problem very clearly.  "*so all I'm trying to do is to write to ttyS0 and transfer data to the raspberry pi*" -- Does this mean that you are sending from the (x86?) *laptop* to the RPi?  So the laptop is running some distro of Linux?